# How to create a function that can apply multiple decorators to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Let's say I have a function that is decorated by multiple decorators.

```
# file.py

@deco1
@deco2('param')
@deco3(
    'multiple',
    'long',
    'params'
)
@deco4('multiple', 'params')
def foo():
    """Function foo
    """
    pass
```

Let's just say it looks very dirty. VERY dirty.

I want to be able to do something like this.

```
# another_file.py

@deco1
@deco2('param')
@deco3(
    'multiple',
    'long',
    'params'
)
@deco4('multiple', 'params')
def all_decorators_for_foo():
    ...
```

```
# file.py

from another_file import all_decorators_for_foo

@all_decorators_for_foo
def foo():
    """Yay!
    """
    ...
```

Just for the sake of context, the multiple decorators are swagger documentation decorators for sanic framework.

Is it possible in python to achieve something similar to this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators) question does not in any way answer my question. Decorators can anyway be stacked together and used. I want some sort of decorator that can be used in place of all the stacked decorators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)

Comment: @bigbounty no it absolutely doesn't. Please read the question before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you insist on that style of *applying* those decorators to `all_decorators_for_foo`, or could you *pass* them to it as arguments?

Comment: @superbrain Anything that works. I just want my code to look pretty lol. But I also want to have the independence to add more decorators to `foo`. Like I want `@deco1` to be with `foo` and all the others grouped together.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Did you go through the answers in the attached link? If not see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163633/6849682. The answer attached to your question uses the same concept - `decor1(decor2(func))(*args, **kwargs)`. So, it's a possible duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you could. You can make another decorator that returns the decorated function like so:
`all_decorators_for_foo.py`

```py
def all_decorators_for_foo(func):
    return deco1()(
        deco2('param')(
            deco3(
                'multiple',
                'long',
                'params'
            )(
                deco4('multiple', 'params')(
                    func
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

and then in `file.py`

```py
from another_file import all_decorators_for_foo

@all_decorators_for_foo
def foo():
    pass
```