# Repeating decorators for several methods. How to DRYing

Tags: python, decorator, dry, python-decorators

In our code base we used to define an *'action'* to any method that was decorated with a custom decorator function.

The definition of *'action'* kept growing, so more decorators were added. Nowadays, we define an *'action'* to any method that is decorated with 4 (sometimes 5) custom decorator functions (order is relevant as you may expect)

```py
@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
@decorator4
def foo(arg):
  pass
```

We've ended up with several (+50) methods that are repeating this design across our codebase:

```py
@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
@decorator4
def fn1(arg):
  pass

...

@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
@decorator4
@decorator5
def fn50(arg):
  pass
```

I'd like to clean this duplication (when `@decorator4` was added to the definition, we needed to update 50+ places)

I've thought 2 possible solutions here (note that both solutions are equivalent, only changing the syntax):

### 1.- 'Decorator of Decorators' Solution

Briefly:

```
@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
@decorator4
@master_decorator(enable_optional_decorator=False)
def fn1(arg)
```

This decorator would need to accept (at least) one argument for enabling/disabling optional decorators

### 2.- 'Wrapping Class' Solution

```
class MasterDecorator:

  def __init__(self, raw_method, enable_optional_decorator=False):
     pass

  def __call__(self)

...

# no decorators here
def fn1(arg):
  pass


# when calling fn1
MasterDecorator(fn_1)(args)
```

---

Which solution would be better? which would be more pythonist?
is there any better design to remove duplication here?

==EDIT==

[Suggested duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215247/how-to-create-a-function-that-can-apply-multiple-decorators-to-another-function?noredirect=1&lq=1): not asking *How* to create a master decorator but rather which would be a pythonist design for cleaning this duplication

Comment: not exactly, not asking how to create a decorator but rather if that's the pythonist approach

Comment: wuau , closed anyway. such a *friendly community* indeed