# Function/decorator for applying multiple decorators

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function or decorator that can apply multiple decorators at once. Specifically, I have a set of patches that I want to apply multiple times, without having to decorate each single time. For example:

```
    @patch(COLUMNS_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[])
    @patch(BUSINESS_AREA_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[business_areas_mocks])
    @patch(TABLES_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[mock_main_base_table, mock_sub_base_table] + valid_default_tables)
    @patch(TABLES_BY_FILTER_FUNC_PATH,
           side_effect=[mock_filtered_tables_main_group(), mock_filtered_tables_sub_group()])
    @patch(TABLE_COLUMNS_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[default_tables_columns1])
    def test_valid_model(self, *_):

        self.assert_valid_model(model=valid_model)
```

These patches are to be applied to many tests.

1. I tried writing a wrapper to include all of the patches but with this wrapper it seemed like the tests was not executed.
2. I also tried to put the patches in a variable, which was successful, but only with 1 patch at a time:

   ```
   patch_in_variable = patch(COLUMNS_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[])
       def test_valid_model(self, *_):

           patch_in_variable(self.assert_valid_model(model=valid_model))
   ```
3. Last thing I tried was from [How to create a function that can apply multiple decorators to another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215247/how-to-create-a-function-that-can-apply-multiple-decorators-to-another-function), but patches were not applied:

   ```
   def multi_patch(func):
       return patch(COLUMNS_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[])(
           patch(BUSINESS_AREA_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[business_areas_mocks])(
               patch(TABLES_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[mock_main_base_table, mock_sub_base_table] + valid_default_tables)(
                   patch(TABLES_BY_FILTER_FUNC_PATH,
                         side_effect=[mock_filtered_tables_main_group(), mock_filtered_tables_sub_group()])(
                       patch(TABLE_COLUMNS_API_FUNC_PATH, side_effect=[default_tables_columns1])(
                           func
                       )
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   @multi_patch
   def test_valid_model(self, *_):

   self.assert_valid_model(model=valid_model)
   ```